# How to choose everything except some number of items?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have 4 tables.

Every item in the first table is linked through second and third tables to some amount of items in the last table.

Here it is :

[image]

I select all appropriate items (i mean the black ones in the last table) using this code :

```
SELECT DISTINCT a1.Name, a2.Name, st.Name, st.ID
FROM Agents a1
INNER JOIN Agents   a2 ON a1.Owner = 1 AND a1.ID = a2.AgentID
INNER JOIN AgentGTP ag ON ag.AgentID = a2.ID 
INNER JOIN GTP         ON GTP.ID = ag.GTPID
INNER JOIN Stations st ON st.ID = GTP.StationID
```

I need to choose all grey items in the last table.
How can i do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard for me to verify this without data, but this might work;

```
SELECT st.*
FROM Agents a1
JOIN Agents   a2 ON a1.Owner = 1 AND a1.ID = a2.AgentID
JOIN AgentGTP ag ON ag.AgentID = a2.ID 
JOIN GTP         ON GTP.ID = ag.GTPID
RIGHT 
JOIN Stations st ON st.ID = GTP.StationID
WHERE GTP.ID IS NULL
```

Comment: Yep, it's perfect, just what i need, thanks !
But may you explain what do 'RIGHT JOIN' and 'WHERE GTP.ID IS NULL' exactly do here?

Comment: In this case, Stations is the "right" table - meaning all rows are returned whether or not there is a matching row in the "left" table (GTP). So where there is not matching record in GTP, all fields from GTP will show as NULL. Maybe this will explain it a bit better; http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Comment: It's a little bit complicated but understandable.
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is it:

```
SELECT * FROM Stations S
WHERE
    S.ID NOT IN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT st.ID
    FROM Agents a1
    INNER JOIN Agents   a2 ON a1.Owner = 1 AND a1.ID = a2.AgentID
    INNER JOIN AgentGTP ag ON ag.AgentID = a2.ID 
    INNER JOIN GTP         ON GTP.ID = ag.GTPID
    INNER JOIN Stations st ON st.ID = GTP.StationID
)
```

Comment: It helped ! 
But maybe it can be done in one query ? I mean using only one 'select'